# How to create a variable value using $ in the runtime in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a bash as below where i want to use the value of YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL in the echo .

```
#! /bin/bash
TRADE_TYPE=$1 
YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL=YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_template.ctl 

echo $TRADE_TYPE"_CTNL"
```

calling the base as below :

```
./test.sh YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER
```

result expecting in echo : YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_template.ctl

Comment: please explain better

Comment: result expecting in echo : YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_template.ctl , but currently getting : YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL .  how to get the desire result ?

Comment: you are not using your variable : YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL .

Comment: i am trying to build the variable at the runtime by passing the half of the name in the command line .

Comment: This sounds like it might be [Bash FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind changing `TRADE_TYPE` or using a temporary variable then you can use `${!var}` expansion:

```
TRADE_TYPE="hello"
hello_world=1234
TRADE_TYPE="${TRADE_TYPE}_world"
echo ${!TRADE_TYPE}
# will print 1234
```

Comment: if i am passing TRADE_TYPE in the command line .. the above code is not working .. Do u have any solution for this ? i mean if i would like to pass this from command line

Comment: @sabya You should be able to figure out how to wrap it up.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get rid of the typo, **CNTL** vs **CTNL**.
This script does what you want

```
#!/bin/bash

TRADE_TYPE=$1 
YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL=YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_template.ctl 

eval echo "\$${TRADE_TYPE}_CNTL"
```

There is probably a better solution than resorting to *eval*. But you will have to explain what your overall goal is.

Comment: eval echo "\$${TRADE_TYPE}_CNTL"  is giving the result i wanted , Thank you for the respond .. i want to use this value in the script by calling variable : YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL  ..

Comment: [eval is evil.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) Use of `eval` is discouraged. Use `eval` only when there is no other way **AND** when you trust the input arguments to `eval`. See andlrc's answer for the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting something like below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TRADE_TYPE=$1

export TRADE_TYPE

variable="$TRADE_TYPE"_template.ctl

echo $variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Using indirect variable reference:

```
#! /bin/bash

TRADE_TYPE="${1}_CNTL"
YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_CNTL=YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_template.ctl

echo "${!TRADE_TYPE}"
```

When the following is entered at the command line:

```
./test.sh YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER
```

Your result will be:

```
YYY_XXX_SK_REGISTER_template.ctl
```